# É possível realizar update em 1 tabela utilizando condição de outra?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
update ivr_contatos,ivr_campanha set ivr_contatos.tentativas = 0 where ivr_contatos.status = 0 and ivr_contatos.tentativas >= ivr_campanha.qtdtentativas
```

a duvida é, se eu consigo dar update no campo tentativas da tabela ivr_contatos utilizando como premissa o campo status (ivr_contatos) e qtdtentativas (ivr_campanha)

Estrutura das tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados não consigo passar pq ainda não tenho.

Comment: coloca a estrutura das tabelas, e um exemplo dos dados por favor

Comment: @RovannLinhalis esta adicionado a estrutura...

Comment: náo sei se o postgree aceita, mas normalmente eu faço da seguinte forma `update ivr_contatos
set ivr_contatos.tentativas = 0 
where ivr_contatos.status = 0 
      and ivr_contatos.tentativas >= (select qtdtentativas from ivr_campanha where id=ivr_contatos.campanha)`

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Desta forma, ele da erro de relação. : column "ivr_contatos" of relation "ivr_contatos" 
does not exist

Comment: mudando um pouco o código do Rodrigo: `update ivr_contatos set tentativas = 0 where status = 0 and tentativas >= (select x.qtdtentativas from ivr_campanha x where x.id=ivr_contatos.campanha)`

Comment: Rovann, apenas para entendimento, o x. representa um Alias para  a tabela ivr_campanha certo?

Comment: Respondendo a sua pergunta para Rovann, Sim. E para complementar, em relação ao erro que você escreveu, só seguir a orientação do colega, que vai funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou conforme eu queria. Poderia publicar como resposta para eu marcar ela por favor?

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fazer assim:

```
UPDATE ivr_contatos
   SET tentativas = camp.quantidadetentativas
FROM ivr_campanha as camp
WHERE ivr_contatos.campanha = camp.id AND
    ivr_contatos.status = 0 AND 
    ivr_contatos.tentativas >= camp.qtdtentativas
```

Fonte: [Documentação do Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/9.3/postgresql-9.3-A4.pdf) (página 1574)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso:

```
UPDATE ivr_campanha campanha SET CONTENT='VALOR ALTERADO' WHERE campanha.status = 0 AND campanha.id IN
(SELECT contatos.id FROM ivr_contatos contatos WHERE contatos.campanha = campanha.id and campanha.qtdtentativas > contatos.qtdtentativas);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64b8c2/1

Answer (score 0):

É possível também utilizar *joins* em *updades* e *deletes*. No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
update ivr_contatos cont
inner join ivr_campanha camp
    on cont.campanha = camp.id
set cont.tentativas = 0
where cont.status = 0 and cont.tentativas >= camp.qtdtentativas
```

Note que para esse exemplo, estou considerando que a coluna **ivr_contatos.campanha** é a chave estrangeira de **ivr_campanha.id**, ou seja, é por estas colunas que essas tabelas se relacionam.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro, irei testar esta solução.

Comment: ele deu erro de sintaxe no Inner